# Rotate Default Model Orientation

Tags: objects, transforms

Is it possible to rotate a model's default orientation?

For example my object is at rotation 0, 0, 0 
however the model is pointing at what looks to be 90, 90, 90

could it be the way the model was created?
if so is it possible to edit the model so it faces a certain way by default?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Shadowblitz.

Comment: Do you mean that the rotations are reading 0,0,0 in the object's properties but the object appears to be rotated in the 3D view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation you describe is a result of a failure to apply the rotation to the object. It may be possible to edit the model, but I find it is quicker to apply (keyboard shortcut combination:  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  -  <kbd>A</kbd>  as soon as I've made the desired rotation.