# Change default rotation and orientation of imported model?

Tags: export

If you import this OBJ model [this Luigi model](https://poly.google.com/view/0T7eqiMs2pk) in Blender, the model opens face down.

How can you use Blender to change the default orientation and rotation so the model is standing vertically (90 degrees) upon opening the file?

The goal is to export a new OBJ file that lets the Luigi model open in a vertical standing (90 degree) posture.

These questions are similar, but the solutions did not work:

1) Could not apply rotation to entire model (Applying rotation after manually rotating the axes with two-finger panning does nothing. Blender says, "Objects have no data to transform."): [Imported object shows aligned to the wrong axis](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79931/imported-object-shows-aligned-to-the-wrong-axis)

2) Did not work: [Imported object shows aligned to the wrong axis](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79931/imported-object-shows-aligned-to-the-wrong-axis)

3) Could not apply rotation to entire model (Applying rotation after manually rotating the axes with two-finger panning does nothing. Blender says, "Objects have no data to transform."): [Rotate Default Model Orientation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43184/rotate-default-model-orientation)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work but it’s worth a shoot. Manual rotate/move the object to how u want it and the press control + a and apply rotation and location

Comment: Tried that, but it doesn't seem to work? How do you rotate the entire model at once? For instance, if you use the trackpad with two fingers while in Object Mode you can move the whole model at once, but applying rotation does nothing. It says, "Objects have no data to transform."

Comment: Dam not sure, when I get home in and hour I’ll see if I can find a solution if u still need help by then

Comment: Select all the parts of the object then press r to rotate you can also press x/z/y to control which way it rotates

Comment: The model consists of multiple objects. So it's not possible to save the rotation/view after using panning with two fingers while in Object Mode?

Comment: Not sure what u were doing wrong but i got it to work with want i was saying. I fixed it for u https://www.dropbox.com/s/in5dhsbznpy31p6/BudgetLuige1.obj?dl=0

Comment: I am very interested and have just send u a email

Comment: Nothing seems to have come through

Comment: Just came though